# Detail Arrows for List Items in Ionic 4's "ios" Mode

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

Got a small problem with list items, using the latest version of Ionic. According to the documentation for `ion-item`, for the `detail` property:

> If true, a detail arrow will appear on the item. Defaults to false unless the mode is ios and an href, onclick or button property is present.

I am using the default, and this is working fine with `href`, but when I use `(click)` it doesn't show up for "ios" mode. The code is:

```
<ion-item (click)="saveContact()">
```

Am I doing something wrong to get this to work with click handlers?

Comment: Are you testing on the device or on the browser?

Comment: I'm testing both. In both cases, when `ios` mode is active, the detail arrows appear when `href` is used but not for `(click)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked into the source code and it appears to be a bug with Ionic (v 4.1.0). This is from the source code, it appears that if the mode is set to "ios" and isClickable, then the detail arrow is shown.

isClickable() appears to be incorrect since it doesn't take into account the "onClick" and just looks for href and if the button attr is set to true. If button is set to true or href is passed, I do see the arrow with ios mode.

```
 private isClickable(): boolean {
    return (this.href !== undefined || this.button);
  }
```

Then in the render method at line 153, when the the showDetail boolean is set (to show the arrow):

```
const clickable = this.isClickable();
    const TagType = clickable ? (href === undefined ? 'button' : 'a') : 'div' as any;
    const attrs = TagType === 'button' ? { type } : { href };
    const showDetail = detail !== undefined ? detail : mode === 'ios' && clickable;
```

Reference:

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/core/src/components/item/item.tsx

Comment: That's not correct. Including the property means you are explicitly setting it to true, it's just a shorthand for it. I double checked and it just switches it on for all modes, as expected. The only way to get the varied behaviour that is default, is to *not* set the property at all. Otherwise you're giving it an explicit value one way or the other, for all modes. As I said in the question, it works fine using `href`, the only problem is when using `(click)`.

Comment: I created a pull request to fix this issue: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/pull/17708

Comment: Nice, thanks, will keep an eye on the PR for more info :)